# Permission denied errors during installation Step 1 of "Generate your server configuration files" with docker

Tags: docker, azerothcore

when i trying the command of the PART 1 install:
`./bin/acore-docker-generate-etc`

I'm getting permission errors like this:

```
Ruben@Ruben-Server MINGW64 /c/Windows/System32/azerothcore-wotlk (master)
$ ./bin/acore-docker-generate-etc
cp: cannot create regular file 'docker/worldserver/etc/worldserver.conf.dist': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file 'docker/authserver/etc/authserver.conf.dist': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file 'docker/worldserver/etc/worldserver.conf': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file 'docker/authserver/etc/authserver.conf': Permission denied
```

the Step 1 of docker install does not say where to git bash this command at.
i have also tried using the command:
cd azerothcore-wotlk
but i get this error:

```
Ruben@Ruben-Server MINGW64 /c/Windows/System32/azerothcore-wotlk (master)
$ cd azerothcore-wotlk
bash: cd: azerothcore-wotlk: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the azerothcore directory somewhere else. Windows administrator permissions might be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are already in the `azerothcore-wotlk` directory:

```
Ruben@Ruben-Server MINGW64 /c/Windows/System32/azerothcore-wotlk (master)
```

so of course it will not work to type `cd azerothcore-wotlk` since you are already in it

Comment: this is apparently correct. but not addressing my issue of why the command is not working to generate my configuration files

Comment: "Permission denied" error seems clear to me, however I don't use microsoft anymore so can't exactly tell you where to look at (maybe in properties and "execute as administrator")